# Why can't I greet you?

Tags: discussion, behavior

I see many of you don't like greetings for some reason. Before you comment, let me refute some of them already.

One of your arguments is "when someone says hi, they're not really saying hi to me".
Yes they are. Not only to you, but to everybody, because it isn't feasible to greet each person.

What's the big deal with that? Automatic systems for filtering? Come on... do I force you to greet anyone and add it to your questions? No! Why should you force me to NOT greet people? To "save text"? Why not limit vocabulary, BTW, and turn all question into [Simple English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_English)? That would certainly save text.

What about jokes, analogies and other related expressions? Even writing style itself, I myself have a writing style that takes up some more space than possible, and many people do. Should that be fixed to conform to some standards? The important thing is not to type as little as possible, but to be understood. Would you prefer more machine-like questions?

Questions are not programs you need to optimize to avoid losing time. I enjoy knowing someone will read what I wrote, knowing I'm not just writing to a machine that doesn't feel, but to an actual person that might be offended if I downvote, and happy if I help.

Comment: Simple as "Stack Overflow is not a social forum". Nothing personal.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, "Why can't I greet you? Stack Overflow is not a social forum". That makes utterly no sense.

Comment: @gnat, the opinion is the opposite, what I'd like is the opposite.

Comment: gnat's point was simply that this has been discussed by the community before, and it reached a conclusion.

Comment: @joran, that was almost 4 years ago.

Comment: Can you demonstrate that anything of significance has changed in that time? Otherwise, you aren't going to get very far.

Comment: What you downvoters don't see is that I don't like dictatorships. Suggest, don't force. Fortunately, thanks to Unicode control characters (like simple ol' &amp;#001) and characters like "ı", your precious [REGEXs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989) are rendered useless. I will greet you anyway. Goodbye. :)

Comment: Downvotes are people voting against your proposal, this sounds more like a democracy that disagrees with you that a dictatorship (I believe the two are different). (Although stack exchange has both democratic and non democratic elements)

Comment: @RichardTingle, I'm not talking about votes which are part of a democracy, but of votes prohibiting something. Hitler was voted, wasn't he? Remember although a dictatorship-like policy can be given and accepted democratically, it doesn't make it right (or even democratic, but that's debatable). If a bunch of people vote to kill someone, is that democratic? Maybe, but it wouldn't be right. This is an exaggerated example, however, here a similar scenario happens: you vote for people not to greet you, and they don't.

Comment: In a democracy I vote against littering, these greetings are equivalent, am I not allowed to be against littering on the site? (Also hilter was not voted in democratically, he got a leg in democratically then subverted the process by intimidation)

Comment: @Richard, you people have an awkward definition of littering... (also people let Hitler do what he wanted, he could've been stopped before he changed the system)

Comment: Its a closer analogy, why do you think the community as a whole shouldn't be able to decide on a common format? (True, but it's more complicated that hitler just being elected)

Comment: It's worth noting that comments are considered "less important" and if you must put this secondary information in then comments are the place for it

Comment: @RichardTingle, because a law should only restrict a damaging behaviour. Littering damages the environment. "Oh, and greetings damage our free time.": really? I just can't agree with such a thing. (indeed it would be tough, plus back then he was kind of a savior of the economy. Enough History lessons `:)`)

Comment: @JMCF125 Law determines the kind of society we want to live in. How much money is spent on schools, if hospitals are free etc etc. Your actions; adding what some would cause "noise" is polite but also obscures the real content. The two are not compatible: some people may what concise, clear questions and answers, others may want polite questions and answers. Given that the two are not compatible we must vote upon which we want. We have voted, we have decided

Comment: @RichardTingle, «The two are not compatible»: say that again? Excuse me, but I have seen all possible combinations of this. You did give a good example though. The hospitals and schools should be free, no voting required. My point is some things are just right or wrong, and there shouldn't have to be a vote. Would anyone reasonable be revolted by greetings being allowed? There are not just two levels of allowance of greetings, there are three: must greet, may/may not greet, must not greet. From this perspective, you're the one on the extreme.

Comment: @JMCF125 **You have very undemocratic attitudes**, I happen to agree on free schools and hospitals but you seem to wish to impose your view on others and call that democracy?! Imagine we are writing a book (which we sort of are) and we agree on a common format, how the headings will be, what the font size will be. We have a big meeting and decide all that. Then you write your page and say; screw you guys, I'm using font 20, Helvetica, in pink.

Comment: @Richard, you don't see it do you? You are the one restricting my freedom to greet, I can't stress this enough, **I'm not forcing you to do anything**, quite the opposite is happening! Give me one good reason a non-damaging thing should be restricted; and I mean in general, not just greetings. I call for freedom in greetings, and I'm undemocratic? Do I need to give the example of killing a person by votes again!?

Comment: You're ruining our book, our book that we've spent **years** writing. If you want to write your **own** book then do so, but if you want a page in ours then you need to find some consensus with us. And it is damaging; it makes the questions less clear

Comment: @Richard, following your analogy, our book is a community book, where each set of pages of an author is distinct of any other, simply because of the person who wrote it. Each page of the book cannot have the same style as other, as duplicate pages have shown so many times. Why enforce your style on my page? It won't be radically different, just a bit. No page stands out (and even if it did, certainly not badly) because of a few words. **And our book stands out because more than one person, and thus more than one style are in it.** I'm not calling my page for attention, just using my own style.

Comment: Because we have determined that our rules have created an effective system. Other people have used other sets of rules for other sites (You want the forum system btw), many have died out, ours haven't. Ultimately if you don't like this system there are other sites out there. But you don't want to do that because this is where you get your questions answered most effectively. Why is that? Because of the rules that have been put in place. QED you actually like the effects these rules have

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is part of culture of this community:

[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/166308)

might we like it or not. It is not usual; but this community is not usual either.

Comment: and that is one of the best things about SE!

Answer (score 20):

> Questions are not programs you need to optimize to avoid losing time.

They're not programs, but they still need to be optimized to save time and space. People are volunteering their time for free. Get to the point of your question. We'd filter out more useless text if we could.

Comment: I know I certainly wouldn't filter it. You must answer questions as a mental exercise then. :)

Answer (score 11):

It should probably be mentioned that Stack Exchange is not a personal exchange between you and the answerer or a social forum, but that is pretty negative to say, however true.

As is likely reiterated all over the `/about` pages of every Stack Exchange site, we are a high-signal (good content), low-noise (lack of bad content, chatty noise, unprofessional behaviour, etc.) Q&A site, with the goal of having Q&A available for **all**. This is not just for yourself, and we try to stay highly professional about it, lest we degrade into

> OMG I cnt solve ths problem ugh someone look at my code and fix it!!!111!

Hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Note that's sloppiness and carelessness; I'm talking about friendliness and tolerance (they keep removing greetings from my posts, thank God only I can edit my comments).

Comment: @JMCF125 Greetings, however friendly, can, should, and *must* be edited out as they offer nothing of value to the question. This is community consensus, and you cannot ever hope of changing this alone. It was decided very early on in SO's history that we would adopt this model.

Comment: Ok then. At least now I'm absolutely sure of the community's opinion.